# forcing to ignore some url parameters

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, parameters, asmx

I am making an iPhone app where I am using .NET webservice.

Let's say below is the URL I have.

```
http://www.myweb.com/wser.asmx/listOfStudents?class=12
```

Here I was getting list of students with below fields in it.

```
Name
Roll Number
Class
```

Now client asked to make arabic version. So we update the query to below.

```
http://www.myweb.com/wser.asmx/listOfStudents?class=12&appLang=ar
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

For testing we update webservice on another server & checked and all is working fine.

Now while uploading app on App store, I noticed if I update actual webservice current app won't work as appLang variable is missing in current app that is there on app store.

If I don't update webservice & apple go in testing, the app will crash as it will throw error of missing parameter appLang.

So what I was thinking is,

I will upload new webservice, BUT appLang will be arabic BY-DEFAULT.

Like if I execute url `http://www.myweb.com/wser.asmx/listOfStudents?class=12` with updated webservice (appLang added in webservice but not in url), it will not throw error of `parameter missing appLang`?

Is there any way to make default parameter?

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while using GET isn't that pretty in this case (POST could be more suitable), you could do this :

```
//by specifying a messageName, you can do overloading with webmethods
[WebMethod (MessageName = "listOfStudentsDefault")]  
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]
public string listOfStudents(int class, string appLang)
{
    // code here...
}

[WebMethod (MessageName = "listOfStudents")]  
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]
public string listOfStudents(int class)
{
    return listOfStudents(class, "ar");
}
```